# How can I prove the equality of $\sup(A)$ and $sup(A\setminus B)?$

Tags: calculus, real-numbers, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

If $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a set bound from above, and $A$ does not have a maximal value, and $B\subseteq A$ and $B$ has a maximal value, how can I prove that $\sup(A)=\sup(A\setminus B)$?

Doesn't this seem impossible?

Comment: Let $b=\sup B.$ Then $b\in B$ and thus $A\setminus B\supset \{a\in A\mid a>b\}=A_b.$ Since $b\in A,$ you only really need to prove $\sup(A_b)=\sup(A)$ for each $b\in A.$

Comment: I suppose you also need that if $X\subseteq Y$ then $\sup(X)\leq \sup(Y).$

Comment: In fact you can show, for any $A$ and any $b<\sup(A),$  $\sup(A_b)=\sup(A).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ has a maximum there exists some $a \in A$ such that $b \leq a$ for all $b \in B$. Since $A$ does not have a maximal value there exists some $x > a$ with $x \in A$, otherwise $a$ would be maximal. Since all $x > a$ are not in $B$ we have $\sup (A \setminus B) = \sup A$.